# Bootstrap 4 alpha 6 nav-tabs align item right

Tags: bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a tab menu that has `nav-item dropdown` to the far right of the menu.

Bootstrap 4 alpha 5, with `float-xs-right` its working: http://codeply.com/go/FCFPpRqhZd

Bootstrap 4 alpha 6, i changed to `float-right` but it isnt working: http://codeply.com/go/5mddDUv1M6

Have idea?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since alpha 6 is now flexbox, `float` will no longer work in this case.

Use the `ml-auto` utility class instead for `margin-left:auto`

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link active">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 4</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown ml-auto">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Account</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/hhV1aM49zz

Comment: This should be on the docs, because after reading https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/ I made a conclusion, that there's only `mr-auto`. Looks obvious what `mr-` and `ml-` stand for now :)

Comment: This works for a single item.  I am looking for a solution to handle multiple items on the right.  I need some items on the left, and then some items on the right

Comment: I am wrapping another ul within the rightmost li to fit multiple items at the right: <ul class="nav nav-tabs justify-content-end"> ...

Comment: @Green. What do you mean? This question is for aligning an item (li) not the `nav-tabs`.

Comment: @techguy2000 I had the same problem. There is an example on how to achieve this: https://www.codeply.com/go/WtDULmFF9G/bootstrap-4-right-align-tabs

Answer (score 1):

If you want to align multiple items to the right within the navbar, there is an example:

```html
<div class="container py-3">
    <div class="col-10 mx-auto">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs small" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab11" role="tab">First</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item ml-auto"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab22" role="tab">More</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab33" role="tab">More 2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content py-4">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab11" role="tabpanel">
                <h2 class="mb-3">Right Align Individual Tabs</h2>
                <p>The above tabs use `ml-auto` to right align indiviual tabs</p>

            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab22" role="tabpanel">
                <div class="card border-primary mb-3">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h3 class="card-title">Primary</h3>
                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Outline</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card border-primary mb-3">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h3 class="card-title">Primary</h3>
                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Outline</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab33" role="tabpanel">
                More..
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

An example fiddle can be found here: https://www.codeply.com/go/WtDULmFF9G/bootstrap-4-right-align-tabs.

The trick here is to set the `ml-auto` class on the **first element (From left to right)** you want to align to the right **only**.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using bootstrap 5, and above, use `ms-auto` or `me-auto` instead of `ml-auto` or `mr-auto`

```
<div id="tunnellines">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tunnelsTab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <button class="nav-link active" id="rdMain-tab" type="button"
                data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#rdMain"
                role="tab" aria-controls="rdMain" aria-selected="true">
                <strong>RD</strong>
            </button>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <button class="nav-link" id="cuMain-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab"
                data-bs-target="#cuMain" type="button"
                role="tab" aria-controls="cuMain" aria-selected="false">CU</button>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item ms-auto">
            <div class="btn-group float-end" role="group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Search
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">
                    Add
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
                    Delete
                </button>

                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
                        data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                        aria-expanded="false">
                        Action
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Formulla</a></li>
                        <li class="divider">
                            <hr />
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reports</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>

    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="tunnelsTabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="rdMain" role="tabpanel"
            aria-labelledby="rdMain-tab" tabindex="0">
            . . .
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="cuMain" role="tabpanel"
            aria-labelledby="cuMain-tab" tabindex="0">
            . . .
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```