# Bootstrap 4 right align button on nav tabs stops the border

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am placing a button on the right side of my nav-tabs but it causes the line to stop just before the button's position. This is not a functional issue but looks just like bad quality design.

The button should not be placed inside a list item but remain on it's own, so [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41980445/3098783) does not work in my case. Is there a solution for this without additional css?

Example Code:

```html
<div class="clearfix">
    <span class="float-right">
      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">
        Button 1
      </button>
      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">
        Button 2
      </button>
    </span>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7dg9zaex/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make the container flexbox (`d-flex`), and use the border utils on the button container.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex mt-3">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs flex-grow-1 flex-nowrap">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <span class="ml-auto text-nowrap border border-top-0 border-left-0 border-right-0">
          <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">
            Button 1
          </button>
          <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">
            Button 2
          </button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/pjghMZZxdp)

Comment: The result looks exactly as I required it to.